# Xamarin Android WindowSoftInputMode does not work on fragment in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

Have a Xamarin Android app but I am sure this question applies to non-Xamarin as well. Most of my fragments have EditText controls. Each time they receive focus, the soft keyboard shows as expected. However, the soft keyboard will cover my EditText boxes on the lower half of the View.

I saw that I can set the following in either the Activity class attribute or the manifest. I am setting this in the Activities class attribute:

```
    [Activity(Label = "MainActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/AppTheme", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

As you can see, I am setting WindowSoftInputMode to AdjustResize. The good news is that I can confirm that this does in fact work for the EditText controls that are on the actual MainActivity.

However, from my MainActivity which works, I also put fragments in to a FrameLayout. So, my MainActivity axml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sortingpackages">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutControls"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/odenlogotransscaled"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/spSelectLocation"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:dropDownWidth="220dp"
            style="@style/SpinnerOdenTheme" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/tbUserLogin"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/UserLogin"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@drawable/EditTextStyle"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:padding="3dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="@string/Login"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            style="@style/TextButtonOdenTheme" />
        <Button
            android:text="@string/Exit"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogoutExit"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            style="@style/TextButtonOdenTheme" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/Settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="@style/TextButtonOdenTheme" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/LoginFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see I put the FrameLayout for the Fragment Container towards the bottom. Any fragment I swap into this FrameLayout using the Support Fragment Manager, does not respect the Soft keyboard setting and resize or pan (I have tried both settings).

I have also tried wrapping either the FrameLayout or the whole Layout inside of a ScrollContainer as suggested by a post I was reading and nothing fixes the problem.

Anybody else have an issue getting the fragments in a FrameLayout to adjust to the soft keyboard and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of your device ，i run fine by set `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden|SoftInput.AdjustPan`  on 7.0 and 8.0，or you could try to add `android:fitsSystemWindows= "true"` to your acticity's root layout

Comment: @LeoZhu I have set the minimum compatibility to 6.0 Marsh. However, the compile SDK is 8.1 Oreo and that is the device that it is running on. I will try again with the exact WindowSoftInputMode and the setting for fitsSystemWindows. I will let you know what I find. When you say you run fine, I am assuming that you also have a FrameLayout within the root layout and have put one or more fragments in the FrameLayout container and even those fragments scale fine?

Comment: yes,i also have a Framelayout within the root and put one fragment in the FrameLayout(i use a scrollview in the root layout)

Comment: Just a side issue, and nothing to do with your problem (and I am willing to be corrected) but your label should not be the name of your activity, but the title of your project. Otherwise, if it is not addressed elsewhere, when you install the app, the launcher icon will show "MainActivity" instead of the project title. This is usually "@string/app_name" where app_name is the project name.